# Spring - injection java.util classes

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on java.util classes injection, with Spring.

I wonder, do you register your bean classes like `Scanner` or `Random` in Spring's context?

I guess this decision depends on how often you will use it, right?

What is the number of usages when I should consider returning bean instead of creating a new object?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want multiple beans to share a single source of random numbers? If so, then the beans needs to be injected with a random number generator bean.

It is however recommended to use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) in a multi-threaded program (for better performance), and it doesn't hurt in a single-threaded program, so general recommendation is to use that, which means `Random` should never be a Spring bean.

However, if you need to unit test code, using a seeded random number sequence, then code needs to be injected with a random number bean that can be mocked.

Note however, that such random number bean is not the `Random` class itself, but a wrapper/helper bean.

---

Do you want multiple beans to share a single `Scanner`?

That question really only makes sense in a command-line program, reading `System.in`, in which case answer is yes.

Comment: Sharing a `Scanner` as a bean still doesn't make sense. Your program will be much saner if you are passing anything of that sort as a method parameter.